# Cannot resolve variable _csrf in Spring MVC Application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

i have been trying to add xss protection via including the code

```
 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

While execution it passes

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
```

My SecurityConfig File is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/app/")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/app/login")
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Is there anything i want to add?

Comment: How do you render your html ?

Comment: what is your controller method type get or post?